# Global Fiber Optic Data

Tags: data-request, telecom

Are there any Open data sources for fiber optic cable locations.  Specifically sub-sea.  I've been searching online and unable to find anything, besides paid services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with this one.  http://www.cablemap.info/ has current and future cables.  Data can be downloaded as shp and kml.

Answer (score 3):

[TeleGeography's Submarine Cable Map](http://www.submarinecablemap.com/) offers the [entire map in a repository on GitHub](https://github.com/telegeography/www.submarinecablemap.com)